# Magento2 : Keep discount always be visible even when it's 0

Tags: magento2

Is there anyway even if there 0 discount but it should always be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to display discount even if it's 0

**Method 1: Override `discount.js` file:**

Override **isDisplayed()** function from `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/totals/discount.js`

> app/design/frontend/Magento_SalesRule/web/js/view/cart/totals/discount.js

**Change from**

```
isDisplayed: function () {
    return this.getPureValue() != 0; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
}
```

**To**

```
isDisplayed: function () {
    return true;
}
```

**Method 2: Override `discount.html`**

Override `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

> app/design/frontend/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

Remove knockout condition

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Final discount.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply but it didn't work for me...

Comment: This must be work. Please check any third party module which override discount file.

Comment: Hi it's showing on cart page but not in checkout? Do u have any idea to make it even visible on Checkout page?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.16 and thid did not work for me.

Comment: @PrincePatel i have apply same code in checkout summery and rule is working but 
coupon title is mising http://prntscr.com/pkf4vw
i want to when apply my coupon code and showing title also discount price 0 not always